# Makefile variable expansion/evaluation

Tags: makefile

Currently I am facing an issue with my Makefile caused by evaluation of a make variable. I have reduced the complexity, only the essential elements remain that produce the issue.

- *$(LIST)* is evaluated as a list of files when the Makefile is read.
- During *step1* one of those files is deleted.
- When using the variable in *step2* it is not evaluated again and thus not valid any more which leads to an error during the copy command.
- It would be nice if the variable was evaluated at the time it is used, here during *step2*.

Any ideas how to solve or work around this issue?

---

**Makefile:**

```
LIST=$(wildcard src/*.txt)

all: step1 step2

step1:
    @echo "---------- step1 ----------"
    @echo $(LIST)
    rm src/q1.txt
    ls src

step2:
    @echo "---------- step2 ----------"
    @echo $(LIST)
    cp $(LIST) ./dst
```

---

**Execution logging:**

```
$ make
---------- step1 ----------
src/q1.txt src/q2.txt
rm src/q1.txt
ls src
q2.txt
---------- step2 ----------
src/q1.txt src/q2.txt
cp src/q1.txt src/q2.txt ./dst
cp: cannot stat `src/q1.txt': No such file or directory
make: *** [step2] Error 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the wildcard function.

```
LIST = src/*.txt

all: step1 step2

step1:
    @echo "---------- step1 ----------"
    @echo $(LIST)
    rm src/q1.txt
    ls src

step2:
    @echo "---------- step2 ----------"
    @echo $(LIST)
    cp $(LIST) ./dst
```

Comment: The reason this works is that the string "src/*.txt" is placed verbatim into the `echo` and `cp` commands, where the shell expands it  again for each command (instead of `make`, which did the expansion of `$(wildcard)`).

Comment: since the variable is expanded when the recipe is invoked (it used "=" for deferred expansion not ":=" for immediate, or simple, expansion) you would expect the original makefile to work.  Here's the problem: for efficiency GNU make caches the contents of directories as it goes.  So, if you make changes to the directory structure in a way make doesn't recognize, you can get into these situations where make's idea of what files exist doesn't match with reality.